# italic and roman counters side by side

Tags: counters, roman

I created two tex commands for roman and arabic counters. The optional parameter sets the first number.

Both commands work if i delete the other. But if together, the roman command return also arabic result.

Any help in debugging would ne appreciated. Below is a MWE:

```
\documentclass{letter}
\setlength\parindent{0pt}

%% command \idt.
%% usage \idt[1] gives (i), then \idt gives (ii), (iii), (iv)...
\newcounter{idtc} \setcounter{idtc}{0}
\makeatletter
\def\idt{\@ifnextchar[{\@first}{\@next}}
\def\@first[#1]{\setcounter{idtc}{#1}{\it \bfseries{(\roman{idtc})} \ }}
\def\@next{\stepcounter{idtc}{\it \bfseries{(\roman{idtc})} \ }}
\makeatother

%% command \udt.
%% usage \udt[1] gives (1), then \udt gives (2), (3), (4)...
\newcounter{udtc} \setcounter{udtc}{0}
\makeatletter
\def\udt{\@ifnextchar[{\@first}{\@next}}
\def\@first[#1]{\setcounter{udtc}{#1}{\it \bfseries{(\arabic{udtc})} \ }}
\def\@next{\stepcounter{udtc}{\it \bfseries{(\arabic{udtc})} \ }}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

Résultat avec $\backslash idt$: \\

\idt[1] Should be {\it \bfseries{(i)}}.\\
\idt Should be {\it \bfseries{(ii)}}.\\ \\

Résultat avec $\backslash udt$: \\

\udt[1] Is correct.\\
\udt Is correct.\\

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not clear why you are using low level `\def` instead of `\newcommand` which can define commands with optional arguments.

But

```
\def\idt{\@ifnextchar[{\@first}{\@next}}
```

means that if you do not use `\[` then the command `\@next` is run. You define `\@next` twice using `\def` so the first definition is discarded and it is defined as

```
\def\@next{\stepcounter{udtc}{\it \bfseries{(\arabic{udtc})} \ }}
```

and produces arabic.

Note the `\\`  in the example all produce

```
Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 29--30
```

which is the maximum level of badness that TeX assigns to its output.

```
\documentclass{letter}
\usepackage{parskip}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
%% command \idt.
%% usage \idt[1] gives (i), then \idt gives (ii), (iii), (iv)...
\newcounter{idtc}
\newcounter{udtc}

\newcommand\idt[1][\relax]{%
\ifx\relax#1\stepcounter{idtc}\else\setcounter{idtc}{#1}\fi
{\itshape \bfseries{(\roman{idtc})} | }\ignorespaces}

\newcommand\udt[1][\relax]{%
\ifx\relax#1\stepcounter{udtc}\else\setcounter{udtc}{#1}\fi
{\itshape \bfseries{(\arabic{udtc})} | }\ignorespaces}


\begin{document}

Résultat avec $\backslash idt$:


\idt[1] Should be {\itshape \bfseries{(i)}}.

\idt Should be {\itshape \bfseries{(ii)}}.

Résultat avec $\backslash udt$: 

\udt[1] Is correct.

\udt Is correct.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Very old-fashioned programming style…

Here's a more modern implementation, where a wrapper is defined for similar commands and then the two main ones are defined in terms of it.

```
\documentclass{article}
%\usepackage{xparse} % uncomment if using a LaTeX release prior to 2020-10-01

\newcounter{idtc}
\newcounter{udtc}

\NewDocumentCommand{\dtgeneric}{mmo}{%
  % #1 = counter name
  % #2 = counter representation
  % #3 = optional value to set the counter to
  % set the counter (if optional argument is present) or step it
  \IfValueTF{#3}{\setcounter{#1}{#3}}{\stepcounter{#1}}%
  \textbf{\textit{(#2{#1})}} \ \ignorespaces
}
\NewDocumentCommand{\idt}{}{\dtgeneric{idtc}{\roman}}
\NewDocumentCommand{\udt}{}{\dtgeneric{udtc}{\arabic}}

\begin{document}

Résultat avec \verb|\idt|

\idt[1] Should be {\itshape\bfseries{(i)}}.

\idt Should be {\itshape\bfseries{(ii)}}.

Résultat avec \verb|\udt|:

\udt[1] Is correct.

\udt Is correct.

\end{document}
```

[image]